# Installing a fresh downloaded php package ubuntu server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I am trying to setup my ubuntu server, but it seems to me that the php package downloaded has got corrupt as it is not installing the whole package.

When I am trying to reinstall after removing the package with `sudo apt-get install php5` it uses the same package which it had downloaded earlier but i want to download a fresh copy how can i do it?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running:

```
locate php5 | grep .deb
```

Or just clean the apt-cache:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```